# Close SVG path (Z) with control points?

Tags: svg, bezier

I draw SVG path like this:

Start:

```
M x, y
```

Add Curve

```
Q x1, y1, x, y
```

etc etc.... and when I want to close path I just add `Z`

But that last line segment now doesn't have any control points.

How can I close path and also have control points on that last segment?

Something like : `Z Q x1, y1` where Z closes path (current point to first point) but it uses x1 and y1 as control points, not just straight line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand your desire. Every time I draw a freehand blob in Illustrator I always set the final point on the original point and then drag to create a tangent for the control points on either side.

SVG has no such feature like this. There is no [path command](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands) that does this. The closest are the shorthand path commands `S` and `T`, but these derive the *first* control point from the last control point on the *previous* command, whereas what you want is something that derives the *second* control point from the first control point on the *next* command (wrap-around style).

You could do this with JavaScript, e.g. markup like

```
<path d="… Z" class="smooth-close" />
```

…and a small script that finds all the `smooth-close` paths, determines the appropriate control point from the first commands and generates a `S` or `T` command and appends it to the path data. But since you did not tag your question with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) I assume such a solution would not interest you.

Comment: I didn't tagged it as javascript because I wanted to know if SVG supports it. I am using fabricJS for drawing paths on canvas and it is behaving exactly like SVG. I could add one more line form current point to first point and visually close path and then call Z. But still it would leave that one line with no control points.

Comment: FWIW if you use Adobe Illustrator to create an ellipse from two points (and four control points) you get path data like `M0,0 c0,-50,100,-50,100,0 S0,50,0,0 z`; so, it does what I was describing with the JavaScript above, manually closing the curve with a control point that happens to tangentially mirror the first control point. And then, as you say, it still throws in a (superfluous) zero-distance `z` to officially close the path.

Comment: I did as I described. I just added normal curve but for the curve's end I gave path's start coords. And then I path closed with Z. And in my implementation I know if I pressed that point and then I control path's start and end. (Hope you understand, don't know how to explain better)